# Why can't I run Alice3 in my computer with Ubuntu 14.04;

Tags: software-installation

I have downloaded and installed Oracle JDK8. I've downloaded the Universal Installer from the site alice.org and then I unzipped it in my home directory.

Why could possibly my computer returns the:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.alice.stageide.EntryPoint
hit enter key to close shell
/home/anbartzi/Alice3/alice3.sh: 3: read: arg count
```

when I try to run Alice3 with the command:

```
 sh ~/Alice3/alice3.sh
```

I would appreciate very much any answer that could help me.
Thank you apriori!

Comment: "when I try to run Alice3 with the command:" and then what? Also I see there is a dedicated linux installer in that site, did you try it?

Comment: The java runtime link on the alice site does point to the obsolete 7u7 version, and I am running alice3 successfully on the jdk 7 for what it's worth.

Comment: How did you get OpenJDK 8? It's not in the Ubuntu repos...

Comment: I used the commands: $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

Answer (score 0):

The application is probably looking for its files in the current directory, so instead of running `sh ~/Alice3/alice3.sh`, change to the containing directory

```
cd ~/Alice3/
```

and then run

```
sh alice3.sh
```

If you don't want to invoke the application using `sh`, you can make the launch script executable using `chmod +x alice3.sh` and then run it from the `Alice3` directory using `./alice3.sh`

Comment: it was so simple! Thank you very much again!!! Do you know any way to run the application through an icon from the desktop;